# постоянно обновляется app.module. AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Есть рабочий сервис, но я его объявляю в одном файле с app.config и app.run

```
var app = angular.module("appTest", ['ui.router', 'ngCookies']);

 app.service('AuthService', function ($cookies, $http, $location) {
 return {
     login: function (response) {
         $cookies.put('token', response.data.access_token);
         $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + 
response.data.access_token;
         $location.path("/private");
     },

     logout: function () {
         $cookies.remove('token');
         $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic';
         $http.get("/api/account/logout")
             .then(function onSuccess(response) {
                 $location.path("/");
             })
             .catch(function onError(response) {
                 console.log('Error')
             });
     },
     checkUser: function () {
         var token = $cookies.get('token')
         if (token) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false
         }
     },

 }
})


app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
 function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, 
$rootScope, toState) {
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
     $stateProvider
         .state('header', {
             url: '/header',
             templateUrl: '/app/pages/header.html'
         })

         .state('home', {
             url: '/',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/home.html',
             controller: 'HomeController',
             authenticate: false,
         })

         .state('education', {
             url: '/education',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/education.html',
             controller: 'EducationController',
             authenticate: false,


         })

         .state('blog', {
             url: '/blog',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/blog.html',
             controller: 'BlogController',
             authenticate: false,
         })

         .state('contacts', {
             url: '/contacts',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/contacts.html',
             controller: 'ContactsController',
             authenticate: false,
         })



         .state('films', {
             url: '/films',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/films.html',
             controller: 'FilmsController',
             authenticate: false,
         })

         .state('books', {
             url: '/books',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/books.html',
             controller: 'BooksController',
             authenticate: false,
         })

         .state('mistakes', {
             url: '/mistakes',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/mistakes.html',
             controller: 'MistakesController',
             authenticate: false,
         })

         .state('login', {
             url: '/login',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/login.html',
             controller: 'LoginController',
             authenticate: false,
         })

         .state('private', {
             url: '/private',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/private.html',
             controller: 'PrivateController',
             authenticate: true,
         });
 }]);


 app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'AuthService', '$location', function 
 ($rootScope, $state, AuthService, $location) {
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams) {
        if(toState.authenticate)
        {
            if(!AuthService.checkUser())
            {
                $location.path("/login");
            }
        }
    });
}
]);
```

В данном примере все работает. Сервис авторизации также принимается и работает в других контроллера. Как только я его вынесу в другой файл и в кофиге закомичу сервис, то сразу ошибка. $ingector. Хочется что б все было "как у людей", в разных файлах так как придется в дальнейшем создавать сервисы. Спасибо

http://prntscr.com/mh58h3

Порядок подключения скриптов

1. Библиотеки ангулара
2. Сервис авторизации
3. app.config
4. другие контроллеры

Я менял порядок уже много раз, толку никакого. Если перенести сервис на последние место, то запустит лишь часть первой страницы.

Вот так выглядит страница index. Хч, может это важно. И еще вопрос, может ли данная проблема быть связана, то на компе нету node и npm в проекте?

```
<body ng-app="appTest">
<div>
    <div ng-controller="HeaderController">
        <div ng-include="'/app/pages/header.html'"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="margindiv"  ui-view="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать следующую структуру проекта и порядок подключения скриптов.

[image: Edit static]

При данном способе подключения node и npm не нужны. Так как скрипты подключаются напрямую.

Слушатель `$stateChangeStart` в `angular-ui-router > 1.0` устаревший. Поэтому использовал $transition, но для ответа на ваш вопрос полагаю это несущественным.
И сделал авторизацию примитивной - по кнопке записывается `token` в `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Спасибо, буду вечером дома, попробую и отпишусь

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за проделанную работу, да, все работает как надо да и еще на последних версиях, продолжу проект в этой архитектуре

Comment: и еще вопрос, в файле app.js  на 17 строке вы я так понимаю что  подключаете типа ng-module на html в блок где id=root? посути єто синоним если б вы вставили вот так  <div ng-module="myApp" id="root">?

Comment: Да, с небольшим уточнением, это синоним, `<div ng-app="myApp" id="root">`.